# How to bind array of objects from Promise Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, promise, yelp

I have a method which returns promise with an array of complex objects via yelp api.
I need to bind it with markup by data-bind="foreach: objects", but I can't.
I need to understand how to bind data in markup, and how to work with promises in observable arrays.
Can anyone help?

```js
//getDataForPlaces
var getDataForPlaces = function(addresses){
 return Promise.all(Array.prototype.map.call(addresses, function(address)    {
      return getLocationDesc(address);
   }));
 
};


//getLocationDesc

var getLocationDesc = function(address){
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   var parameters = [];
            parameters.push(['sort', sort]);
            parameters.push(['limit', limit]);
            parameters.push(['radius_filter', radius_filter]);
            parameters.push(['actionlinks', actionlinks]);
            parameters.push(['location', address]);
            parameters.push(['callback', 'callback']);
            parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_key', auth.consumerKey]);
            parameters.push(['oauth_consumer_secret', auth.consumerSecret]);
            parameters.push(['oauth_token', auth.accessToken]);
            parameters.push(['oauth_signature_method', 'HMAC-SHA1']);

            var message = {
                'action' : 'http://api.yelp.com/v2/search',
                'method' : 'GET',
                'parameters' : parameters
            };

            OAuth.setTimestampAndNonce(message);
            OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);

            var parameterMap = OAuth.getParameterMap(message.parameters);
            $.ajax({
                url : message.action,
                cache : true,
                method : message.method,
                data : parameterMap,
                dataType : 'jsonp',
                jsonp : 'callback',
                success : resolve,
                error : reject
            });
        });
 };


//View model

function MapViewModel(){
 var self = this;
 self.categories = ["Choose option", "Bars", "Gyms"];
 var addresses = ["address","address, address",
  "address","address",
  "address"]; 
 var yelp = new YelpDataProvider();

 self.places = ko.observableArray();

 yelp.getDataForPlaces(addresses).then(function(place){
  self.places(place);
 })
}

ko.applyBindings(new MapViewModel());
```

```html
<ul data-bind="foreach: places ">
  <li data-bind="text: business[0].name"></li>
</ul>
```

complex object:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you're in the right way. The similar code works as expected http://jsfiddle.net/xe9geqhy/2/ What do you have here `self.places(place);` Seems like, you fill an observableArray with object(not array) and then, in the markup, you try to iterate by it.

Comment: I used your advice, it works, but how to get the object in the markup?

<ul data-bind="foreach: places ">
      <li></li>
     </ul>

Comment: What do you mean `how to get the object in the markup`? Could you provide the `self.places` array?

Comment: How do I iterate this JSON(see the picture with json model above)  using Knockout.js foreach binding?

<ul data-bind="foreach: places ">
      <li>
<p data-bind="text: ???????">
</li>

Comment: As far as I understand, you can use something like this http://jsfiddle.net/xe9geqhy/3/

Comment: i think you are looking something similar as [How to use knockout to iterate over an object (not array)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838135/how-to-use-knockout-to-iterate-over-an-object-not-array)

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a conceptual issue going on here.

If `MapViewModel()` is a constructor, it will be called with `new`. However, the `getLocationDesc()` aspect of the constructor is asynchronous, with the consequence that, as written, `new MapViewModel()` will return an object which is effectively still under construction, and with no access to a promise to signify completion of the async process.

Constructors and asynchronism don't mix.

A workaround is to put the async stuff inside a public `.getLocationsAsync()` method. Something like this maybe :

```
function MapViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.categories = ["Choose option", "Bars", "Gyms"];
    self.places = ko.observableArray();
    var addresses = ["address", "address, address", "address", "address", "address"];
    var yelp = new YelpDataProvider();
    var locationsPromise = null;// a var in which to cache the promise created by this.getLocationsAsync()
    this.getLocationsAsync = function() {
        if(!locationsPromise) {
            locationsPromise = Promise.all(addresses.map(yelp.getLocationDesc)).then(function(placeDescriptions) {
                placeDescriptions.forEach(function(p) {
                    places.push(p);
                });
                return places;
            });
        }
        return locationsPromise;
    };
}
```

*Probably not 100% correct but hopefully good enough to illustrate the idea.*

Now call as follows :

```
var mapViewModel = new MapViewModel();
mapViewModel.getLocationsAsync().then(function(places) {
    // places is an observableArray
});
```

Note: To be truly useful, you probably want to pass `addresses` and `categories` to `MapViewModel()`, otherwise every instance will be identical. Or maybe `MapViewModel()` should be rephrased as a singleton?